# Correct using of broadcast in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, broadcast

Lets say that I have an RDD such as(using pyspark):

```
 RDDstrings = sc.parallelize(['alpha','alpha4','veta','gamma','delta'])
```

and I want to compare each string with the others by using a string distance function. So the final result in that case would be a 5x5 matrix with diagonals to be of value `1` as the string value is compared with its own value at the diagonals.

So, my idea was the following:

1. I created a function `StringDistance(string,alist)` which take as input a `string` to be compared with `alist` of strings.
2. Broadcast the `RDDstrings`:

   ```
   broadcastedRDDstrings = sc.broadcast(RDDstrings.collect())
   ```
3. Map the initial RDD:

   ```
    stringsDistances = RDDstrings.map(lambda string:StringDistance(string,broadcastedRDDstrings.value))
   ```

So in this transformation I compare each string from the initial RDD with the same RDD strings which was broadcasted later.

The results are correct. But my question is if this is the best way to implement it and if this is a correct usage of broadcasting. Or should I `cache()` the initial RDD?

Any negative feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach.

```py
def patheticDistance(a, b):
    return len(a) - len(b)

rdd = sc.parallelize(["maritza", "alberto", "andres", "dakota", "miguel"]).sortBy(lambda x: x)

distances = (rdd.cartesian(rdd)
                .groupByKey()
                .map(lambda (x, y): [patheticDistance(x, a) for a in y])))

distances.collect()
# [[-1, 0, 0, -1, 0],
#  [-1, 0, 0, -1, 0],
#  [ 0, 1, 1,  0, 1],
#  [-1, 0, 0, -1, 0],
#  [ 0, 1, 1,  0, 1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cartesian` method on RDD, like

`rdd.cartesian(rdd)`